# flutter web blank screen after importing cloud firestore dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

flutter web blank screen after importing cloud firestore dependency
and work well after removing it
and by running with debugging this error appears

---

web_entrypoint.dart

```
// @dart=2.12
// Flutter web bootstrap script for package:booky/main.dart.

import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:booky/main.dart' as entrypoint;
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';
import 'package:booky/generated_plugin_registrant.dart';

typedef _UnaryFunction = dynamic Function(List<String> args);
typedef _NullaryFunction = dynamic Function();
Future<void> main() async {                                       **// this is the error** 
  registerPlugins(webPluginRegistrar);
  await ui.webOnlyInitializePlatform();
  if (entrypoint.main is _UnaryFunction) {
    return (entrypoint.main as _UnaryFunction)(<String>[]);
  }
  return (entrypoint.main as _NullaryFunction)();
}
```

---

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: "^2.5.3"
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
  firebase_core: ^1.8.0
  cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Please review your question and be more specific with your issue.

Comment: It should be `cloud_firestore` not `cloud_firestore_web right`?. Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/), and note the things about web if you are supporting it.